# Many inputs in a table that are writing at the same time REACT

Tags: reactjs

https://github.com/ShannonManoka/Application

I'm coding an application in React the purpose of it is to show 2 table with in one of them a name and in the other one to have an input for each row  that are predicting what you are typing. My only problem is that if I am typing something in one input all my inputs are writing at the same time. What am I doing wrong ?

```
const INPUT_TIMEOUT = 250;

class OldDataTable extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        value: '',
        predictions: [],
      };

      this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    getPredictions(value) {
      return [
        'Boston',
        'Los Angeles',
        'San Diego',
        'San Franciso',
        'Sacramento',
        'New York',
        'New Jersie',
        'Chicago',
      ].filter(item => item.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
    }
    onChange(e) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
      const value = e.target.value;
      this.setState({
        value
      });

      if (value.length > 0) {

        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          const predictions = this.getPredictions(value);
          this.setState({
            predictions
          });
        }, INPUT_TIMEOUT);
      } else {
        this.setState({
          predictions: []
        });
      }
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <table class='tableOld'>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Old Dataset</th>
              </tr>
            {OldData.map((DataDetails, index)=>{
              return <tr>
                      <td><input type = "text" value={this.state.value} onChange = {this.onChange}/>
                        <div>
                        {
                          this.state.predictions.map((item, index) => (
                            <div key={index + item}>{item}</div>
                          ))
                        }
                        </div></td>
                    </tr>
            })}

            </tbody>
          </table>
        )
    }

}



export default OldDataTable
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that all the inputs are referencing the same single `value` value in state. If you want all separate inputs you'll need a different state value for each.

One option is to interpolate the `index` into the name of each and dynamically store the state value. For example:

```
class OldDataTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  getPredictions(value) {
    return [
      "Boston",
      "Los Angeles",
      "San Diego",
      "San Franciso",
      "Sacramento",
      "New York",
      "New Jersie",
      "Chicago"
    ].filter(item => item.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
  }
  onChange = index => e => {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      [`value${index}`]: value
    });

    if (value.length > 0) {
      this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        const predictions = this.getPredictions(value);
        this.setState({
          [`predictions${index}`]: predictions
        });
      }, INPUT_TIMEOUT);
    } else {
      this.setState({
        [`predictions${index}`]: []
      });
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <table class="tableOld">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Old Dataset</th>
          </tr>
          {OldData.map((_, index) => {
            return (
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state[`value${index}`]}
                    onChange={this.onChange(index)}
                  />
                  {this.state[`predictions${index}`] && (
                    <div>
                      {this.state[`predictions${index}`].map((item, index) => (
                        <div key={index + item}>{item}</div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  )}
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit multiple-inputs]

There were also two other issues with the code:

- Make sure to use `className` (not `class`): `<table className="tableOld">`
- Make sure to add a `key` to the `tr` element. I added `<tr key={index}>` but ideally the `OldData` has some unique identifier that would be better to use. For more details see: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: First of all thank you for your help, I understand the issues with the key in the table.

But when I am using your code, also I installed every packages with npm install I have an error wich is :

Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enable

Comment: Hmm, not sure without seeing how you're building it or a reproducible example. The only thought is the `onChange = index => e =>` syntax. Try rewriting that as `onChange(index) { return (e) => { // remaining contents } }` possibly.

Comment: It showed another issue regarding an Unxpected token . I put my code on GitHub, any help will be welcome because I am really stuck on that. 
 https://github.com/ShannonManoka/Application

Comment: Can you link to it on GitHub?

Comment: Ok I found an another solution to my problem by using the an id for each value of my table. And using that id as a key. Thank you helped me a lot